# Show $-\arg{j_{AB}(z)}+\arg{j_{A}(Bz)}+\arg{j_{B}(z)}$ does not depend on $z$.

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

I'm trying to show $-\arg{j_{AB}(z)}+\arg{j_{A}(Bz)}+\arg{j_{B}(z)}$ does not depend on $z\in\mathbb{H}$ where $A,B\in SL_2{(\mathbb{R})}$ and $j_A(z)=cz+d$, $A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    a       & b \\
    c       & d
\end{bmatrix}$ and the branch cut is made at $\pi$.

The book says it follows from the identity $j_{AB}(z)=j_A(Bz)j_B(z)$ but I don't see why the statement above follows from the identity. I can see that the identity implies

$$-\arg{j_{AB}(z)}+\arg{j_{A}(Bz)}+\arg{j_{B}(z)}\equiv0\mod{(-\pi,\pi]}.$$

And I can also see that $-\arg{j_{AB}(z)}+\arg{j_{A}(Bz)}+\arg{j_{B}(z)}$ takes only 3 possible values, $-2\pi, 0, 2\pi$. However, I really don't see why this expression always takes the same value no matter what $z$ I choose. Can anybody give me some insights?

Comment: $A(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ and $ad-bc=1 \implies A'(z) = \frac{1}{(cz+d)^2}$ so $(A(B(z)))' = A'(B(z))B'(z)$ and $j_{AB}(z)= \pm j_A(B(z))j_B(z)$. Then find the sign assuming $c > 0$ (for both $A,B$) so $Im(cz+d) > 0$ and pick a branch of $\log$ sending $r e^{it}, t \in (0,\pi),r > 0$ to $r+it$. Extend to the case $c=0$ by continuity, finally look at the case $c < 0$.

Comment: I can show the identity $j_{AB}(z)=j_A(Bz)j_B(z)$ without much problem. What I meant is it's not obvious why the fact $-\arg{j_{AB}(z)}+\arg{j_A(Bz)}+\arg{j_B(z)}$ does not depend on $z$ follows from the identity.

Comment: With the conditions I mentioned $-\log(j_{AB}(z))+\log(j_A(Bz))+\log(j_B(z))$ is analytic in $z, Im(z) > 0$ and it takes its values in $2i \pi \mathbb{Z}$, thus it suffices to show that $-\log(j_{AB}(z))+\log(j_A(Bz))+\log(j_B(z)) = 0$ for one $z$ for it to be true for every $z, Im(z) > 0$

Comment: Ah, it was so simple.. Thank you!